# Creating googleApiClient causes android app to crash

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I'm trying to get location services working in an android app, but when I create a `GoogleApiClient` instance (as suggested by Google [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)), the app crashes with this error:

```
--------- beginning of crash
11-01 16:11:44.805 10225-10225/com.company.appname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.company.appname, PID: 10225
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zze com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zza.zza(android.content.Context, android.os.Looper, com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzq, java.lang.Object, com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks, com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$OnConnectionFailedListener)"
  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
  at com.company.appname.MapsActivity.initLocationStuff(MapsActivity.java:50)
  at com.company.appname.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:42)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6757)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1504)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Here is my class:

```
package com.company.appname;

import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileOverlay;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileOverlayOptions;
import com.google.maps.android.heatmaps.HeatmapTileProvider;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
  private GoogleMap mMap;
  private HeatmapTileProvider heatmapProvider;
  private TileOverlay heatmapOverlay;
  private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    initLocationStuff();
  }

  protected void initLocationStuff() {
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
  }

  @Override
  public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.d("DEV", "connected");
  }

  public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.d("DEV", "Google api connection failed " + result.toString());
  }

  public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    final MapsActivity self = this;
    mMap = googleMap;

    new EnvelopeGetter("https://192.168.1.177:8080/api/upvotes", new EnvelopeGetter.CompletionHandler() {
      public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {
        try {
          ArrayList<Upvote> upvotes = Upvote.fromJSONArray(response.getJSONArray("upvotes"));
          ArrayList<LatLng> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();

          for(Upvote upvote : upvotes) {
            coordinates.add(upvote.coordinate);
          }

          self.addHeatMap(coordinates);
          Log.d("DEV", upvotes.toString());
        } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      public void onFail(String errorMessage) {
        Log.d("DEV", errorMessage);
      }
    });
  }

  private void addHeatMap(ArrayList<LatLng> points) {
    Log.d("DEV", "ADDING HEAT MAP " + points.size());
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(points.get(0)));
    heatmapProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder().data(points).build();

    heatmapOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(heatmapProvider));
  }
}
```

And here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.appname"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.kevinsawicki:http-request:6.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

If I comment out the contents of the `initLocationStuff` method, the app does not crash.

Comment: Use the latest version of play services for location like you have used for maps

Comment: Thanks! Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Ok sure right away

Comment: Done, check out my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be caused due to the mismatch of play services API updates it.